# What is the proper way to handle retina images from resized nsdata?

Tags: ios, uiimage, retina-display

When a user selects an image from the their photo library, I'm resizing it and then uploading it to my server and then at some other point in the app the user can view all their photos. (I'm simplifying the work flow)

The uiimageview on the "detail" screen is 320 x 320. Based upon the below method should I be using:

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];`

or

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:img.imageOrientation];`

Part B would be when I request download the image (nsdata) should I use `imageWithCGIImage` or `imageWithCGIImage:scale:orientation`

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImageForUpload:(UIImage *)originalImage {

  static CGSize __maxSize = {640, 640};

  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 1.0)];

  CFMutableDataRef dataRef = (__bridge CFMutableDataRef)data;
  CGImageSourceRef imgSrc  = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(dataRef, NULL);

  CGFloat width = [originalImage maxDimensionForConstraintSize:__maxSize];

  NSNumber *maxWidth    = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:width];
  NSDictionary *options = @{
                            (__bridge NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
                            (__bridge NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: @YES,
                            (__bridge NSString *)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : maxWidth
                            };

  CFDictionaryRef cfOptions     = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options;
  CGImageRef img                = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imgSrc, 0, cfOptions);
  CFStringRef type              = CGImageSourceGetType(imgSrc);
  CGImageDestinationRef imgDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(dataRef, type, 1, NULL);

  CGImageDestinationAddImage(imgDest, img, NULL);
  CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDest);

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];

  CFRelease(imgSrc);
  CGImageRelease(img);
  CFRelease(imgDest);

  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears I've found the answer to my own question. The `resizeImageForUpload` shouldn't try to scale based upon the device. Since I'm defining a max size 640,640 (retina size for my 320,320 uiimageview) no other manipulation is necessary. I've added some caching for the images and I'm handing the scaling at that point:

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];`

and then return. The reason why I thought I had messed something up was that I was trying to scale an *already* scaled image. Lessons learned.